# How to get bank logos using getsite API?

Tags: yodlee, bank

How we able to get bank logos in getsite accounts api ?

I want to display account logo in searchaccount API call.

Which API will return this detail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use get [**getSiteInfo**](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getSiteInfo) API and remember to pass value of `siteFilter.reqSpecifier` as 128, while if you are using SOAP then [**here**](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_SOAP_API_Reference/getSiteInfo) is the reference(remember to pass request specifier as 128).

**EDIT 1: Based on the comment**
You can use this code to convert the Base64 string to image.
Below is the code in JAVA:

```
public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

BufferedImage image = null;
byte[] imageByte;
try {
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
    image = ImageIO.read(bis);
    bis.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return image;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I got this defaultSiteLogo. But i dont know how to convert this to image. 

When i google for this, most options are with converting base64 encoded image format only.

Will anyone help to guide me to get site logo to be save.

Comment: @user3013094 - Please see my edited answer, this should help you.

Comment: I am using REST api. Will u pls provide info on converting the bytes to image with php code ? It will great to help o this now.

Comment: @user3013094 - here is the link for the same http://www.zoubi.me/blog/php-get-image-byte-array I would suggest you to google first and the basic queries and if you are not able to find any solution then please ask the question over here.

Comment: Hi, the link is no longer valid ?

Comment: Thanks @RonakJain For updating REST link, I have also updated SOAP link as well.